# Centered box of text with a border wrapping around it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 8rem;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  color: white;
  text-justify: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Want this:

     -------------
     |Hello world|
     -------------

On all screens big and small, portrait or landscape. */
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

I think I need the text size to change depending on the width of the screen and I don't know how to justify the text inside the box. Furthermore I would the border to be just around the text, not hugging the available width as we see upon: https://s-ckwvolnvzl.now.sh/

Looking for a minimal solution, so if the text resizing is too hard, forget about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [viewport](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) units to make the text resizable.

I've added `justify-content` property to the body to center the text, and changed the `h1` to `display: inline-block` to ensure the border only surrounds the text.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15vw; /* change this value as you need */
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Want this:

     -------------
     |Hello world|
     -------------

On all screens big and small, portrait or landscape. */
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```